# Algorithmic complexity vs real life situations?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, mergesort, bubble-sort

My question is about theory vs practice thing.
Let’s say for example that I want to sort a list of numbers. Mergesort has a complexity of O(n*logn) while bubblesort has a complexity of O(n^2).
This means that mergesort is quicker. But the complexity doesn’t take into account the whole thing happening on a computer. What I mean by that, is that mergesort for example is a divide and conquer algorithm and it needs more space than bubblesort.
So isn’t it possible that the creation of this additional space and usage of resources (time to transfer the data, to populate the code instructions, etc) to take more time than bubblesort which doesn’t use any additional space ?
Wouldn’t be possible to be more efficient to use an algorithm with worse (“bigger”) complexity than another for certain length of inputs (maybe small) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a clear yes.

A classic example is that insertion sort is `O(n^2)`.  However efficient sorting implementations often switch to insertion sort at something like 100 elements left because insertion sort makes really good use of cache, and avoids pipeline stalls in the CPU.  No, insertion sort won't scale, but it outperforms.

The way that I put it is that scalability is like a Mack Truck. You want it for a big load, but it might not be the best thing to take for a shopping trip at the local grocery store.

Comment: I love your Mack Truck analogy.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithmic complexity only tells you how two algorithms will compare as their input grows larger, i.e. approaches infinity.  It tells you nothing about how they will compare on smaller inputs.  The only way to know that for sure is to benchmark on data and equipment that represents a typical situation.

Comment: Nice surname Sir.